# Installing application from a standard user account

Tags: manifest, uac, administrator

I have a MFC application which now requires administrative permission to install from a standard user account.The application currently uses registry's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and installs in program files by default. I want to change it in such a way so that any account ,even without administrative password can install it without administrator privilage. 
my manifest files is currently like this :

```
<ms_asmv2:trustInfo xmlns:ms_asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
 <ms_asmv2:security>
  <ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
    <ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel
      level="highestAvailable"
      uiAccess="false"/>
    </ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
   </ms_asmv2:security>
```

What should i do to ensure the desired result ? I thought of shifting the registry keys to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Is it neccessary? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the model that **Chrome** uses:

> Do not install in **Program  Files**.

Chrome installs itself in the *per-user* `APPDATALOCAL` folder, e.g.:

```
C:\Users\DJ\AppData\Local\DjSoftwidget
```

That way each user can install the app without needing administrative privileges. With that you would manifest your installer as `requestedExecutionLevel` of `asInvoker`.